# How to export / import entire Google Sites?

Tags: export, import, google-classic-sites

Is there a way to export / import an entire Google Site?

If not possible, is there a way to export / import selected pages?

Comment: What do you want to export from or import to Google Sites?

Comment: @dnbrv I want to export/import pages into Google Sites

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/sites/docs/1.0/developers_guide_protocol#CreatingContent

If you set up an OAuth account, you can use the Google Sites API to automatically upload hundreds of web pages.

- https://developers.google.com/gdata/articles/using_cURL
- https://github.com/google/gdata-python-client/blob/master/samples/sites/sites_example.py

See also: [Batch Downloader for Google Site](https://web.archive.org/web/20150702123336/http://www.appservicer.com/batch-uploader-downloader-for-google-site)

Comment: Note that this doesn't (as of December 2018) work with new Google Sites: "A rebuilt version of Sites was launched on November 22, 2016. The Sites API cannot access or modify Sites made with this version, but can still access classic Sites."

Answer (score 4):

There is an official tool by the google liberation front to import and export google sites:

From the website:  "The downloaded site will not be styled and will not include the chrome and is completely unstyled, but will contain all of the content included in the site."

http://web.archive.org/web/20130806050134/http://www.dataliberation.org/google/sites which refers to the tool https://code.google.com/p/google-sites-liberation/

Comment: What tool do you mean? The link now redirects to  https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/3024190 which is clearly an official google site.

Comment: Sorry I got it wrong

Answer (score 1):

You can't import entire pages into Google Sites because of Google's restriction on code. However, you can copy-paste the content (not interactions) through the regular Google Sites editor. ([See Google's Help Center](http://support.google.com/sites/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=90558))

There's also no export or backup option available.

Comment: However, if I have 100 pages, wouldn't I need to repeat this manually for a 100 times?

Comment: Unfortunately, you'll have to repeat that 100 times. Google Sites isn't designed for content migrations. Are you migrating from another content management system?

Comment: Yes I have a folder filled with webpages that I would like to *upload*

Comment: Ah, you migrating from a static site (a CMS would've had a database). So, yeah, Google Sites isn't designed as a destination for a migration. It's best used as the starting point.

Answer (score 1):

if it's all in folders you're going to have to go with ftp hosting from GoDaddy then up the site and either edit code or upload all future changes.  If you are using Dreamweaver this method is pretty easy

If you want to migrate your old non-Google Sites site to Google Sites you have to manually build each page.  after it's built you can 'back it up' in 2 seconds using 'copy this site' which makes a complete copy with a different sub directory name

before going through the time of manually building your new pages know that most script functionality doesn't work in Google Sites for 'security reasons' so parts of your site may not work or look how you want them too.
If you are really set on Google sites I'd suggest starting from scratch as it'll save you a lot of headaches and time
Jon